# Web-view Flutter not sending "origin" and "referer" with the request headers

Tags: flutter, webview-flutter

I am trying to request an URL with the [Web-view Flutter Library](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter/versions)

upon Checking the request I can see that its missing the two Header components - **Origin** and **referer** Which is required for handling the request.

As per my knowledge it should be automatically added with the request.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In flutter_webview case we can utilise the onPageStarted callback method and implant the header**

```
onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                this.webViewController = webViewController;
              },
onPageStarted: (url) {
                webViewController.loadUrl(url, headers: headers);
              },
```